'USER_VM_OPTIONS_FILE' is not recognized as an internal or external command
I've downloaded & installed latest verison of android-studio, added JAVA_HOME in ENV vars, added it to the PATH as well.
Now trying to open android-studio with no luck.
It freezed on the splash screen (screenshot attached below)
Attached Screenshot
I've tried running studio_safe.bat file I found in android-studio\bin folder.
It gives me the following error:
Could Not Find C:\Users\Hamdi Mohamed\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2023.3.safe\idea.properties
'USER_VM_OPTIONS_FILE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
FINDSTR: Cannot open

Start Failed
Internal error. Please refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708

kotlinx.coroutines.JobCancellationException: Parent job is Cancelling; job=UndispatchedCoroutine{Cancelling}@7d65cd7c
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: idea/AndroidStudioApplicationInfo.xml
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationNamesInfo.loadData(ApplicationNamesInfo.java:81)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationNamesInfo.initAndGetRawData(ApplicationNamesInfo.java:102)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationInfoImpl.getShadowInstanceImpl(ApplicationInfoImpl.java:306)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationInfoImpl.getShadowInstance(ApplicationInfoImpl.java:290)
        at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.StartupUtil$startApplication$appInfoDeferred$1$1.invokeSuspend(main.kt:108)
        at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.StartupUtil$startApplication$appInfoDeferred$1$1.invoke(main.kt)
        at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.StartupUtil$startApplication$appInfoDeferred$1$1.invoke(main.kt)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
        at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span(tracer.kt:56)
        at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.impl.TracerKt.span$default(tracer.kt:49)
        at com.intellij.platform.ide.bootstrap.StartupUtil$startApplication$appInfoDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(main.kt:106)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)

-----
Your JRE: 17.0.10+0--11572160 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
G:\jet-brains\android-studio\jbr

Tried opening android-studio many times, expected it to open, but that didn't happen.
It gives me the mentioned error.
